# onchange event crashes entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css, onchange

I am Trying to add an onchange function to three separate elements that will rebuild the calendar if the user changes day, month, or year. The page loads and works fine until I change one of the three values, then it returns only the basic calendar with no css formatting, and all of the other elements from the page are gone. No errors are shown in developer tools.

I have looked at many examples online and I think my syntax is correct. I am calling the function initially on page load, which works fine.

```
<div id="bottomleft"> 
<script type="text/javascript" onload="buildCalendar();">
</script>
</div>
```

I am then calling it on change for each of the three elements as shown below.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="31" step="1" id="myday"    onchange="buildCalendar();">

<select id="mymonth" onchange="buildCalendar();">

<input type="number" min="100" max="2016" id="myyear" onchange="buildCalendar();">
```

My full CODEPEN is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qbEXpJ however for some reason the calendar is not displaying here, although it works fine in chrome.
Please let me know if you see any errors.

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing:

```
document.write("foo")
```

You are actually overriding the entire page, that's why you are getting everything  without css format in the OnChange events. Sounds weird that it actually works with the onload, but you can see in CodePen it won't work there. Try to set up a div and write on it:

```
$("#myDiv").html("foo")
```